# Losing last character in string when reading a value from a line in a CSV

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I'm trying to parse through a line of a CSV file and pull out the desired value that I want.  However, my function is cutting off the last character in the string, and I can't figure out why.  I thought it has something to do with where I'm assigning the null terminator, but changing that didn't help.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
char* findKey(char lineBuffer[], int columnNumber ){
    char tempArray[strlen(lineBuffer)+2];
    int commasCounted = 0;
    int i =0;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(lineBuffer) - 1; i++){
        if (commasCounted == columnNumber){
            commasCounted = i;
            break;
        }

        if (lineBuffer[i] == '\"'){
            i++;
            while(lineBuffer[i] && lineBuffer[i] != '\"'){
                i++;
            }
        }

        if (lineBuffer[i] == ','){
            commasCounted++;
        }
    }

    if(lineBuffer[commasCounted] == ','){
        tempArray[0] = '0';
        tempArray[1] = '0';
        tempArray[2] = '0';
        tempArray[3] = '0';
        tempArray[4] = '\0';
    }else{
        int j = 0;
        for(i = commasCounted; i < strlen(lineBuffer) - 1; i++){
            if(lineBuffer[i] == '\"'){
                i++;
                while(lineBuffer[i] && lineBuffer[i] != '\"'){
                    tempArray[j] = lineBuffer[i];
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }
                break;
            }else if(lineBuffer[i] == ','){
                break;
            }else
                tempArray[j] = lineBuffer[i];
                j++;
        }
        tempArray[j] = '\0';
    }

    char* tempString = strtok(tempArray, "\n");
    //printf("tempString before returning in findKey: %s\n", tempString); //testing
    return tempString;
}
```

The CSV file can have certain columns wrapped in quotes, which is why there are some checks for quotes in there.  This gets passed the string to check, and the column that holds the information.  So, for example:
Passing in this for lineBuffer:

```
30,beforeyoustartedgackinyouusedtohaveabrainbutnowyoudontgeteventhesimpliesofthingsdrawalittlepictureevenusemyhandstrytoexplainbutyoujustdontunderstandoh
```

And a 1 for columnNumber

Results in this being returned:

```
beforeyoustartedgackinyouusedtohaveabrainbutnowyoudontgeteventhesimpliesofthingsdrawalittlepictureevenusemyhandstrytoexplainbutyoujustdontunderstando
```

Comment: you're returning a tokenized string out of a temporary / local string: that's undefined behaviour

Comment: Are you doing this to learn, or is this part of a real application? For the latter, you would be better off using a pre-written CSV library.

Comment: @Barmar To learn

Comment: have you tried to duplicate the line: `char* tempString = strdup(strtok(tempArray, "\n"));`

Comment: I thought this was python, my first comment now removed was "can't you use the `csv` module? lol... There are probably good examples of this here. Study them.

Comment: also it doesn't seem to handle when commas are between quotes...

Comment: "The CSV file can have certain columns wrapped in quotes, which is why there are some checks for quotes in there." Please put a description of the exact format and an actual file in your question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Don't the `while(lineBuffer[i] && lineBuffer[i] != '\"')` loops do that? They ignore any commas before the second quote.

Comment: @Swordfish what do you mean?  I posted the line from the file.  It's contained in `lineBuffer`.
@Jean-FrançoisFabre It does handle quotes correctly.  I've checked it.

Comment: You should be able to figure out your problem if you step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: I have been trying to debug it for awhile now.  I was hoping to get some input because debugging isn't getting me anywhere.  I'm stuck.  @Barmar

Comment: @Locke You got your answer already: You return the address of a function-local variable that seases to exist when the function returns.

Comment: @Swordfish I've already tried changing that.  That doesn't seem to be the issue here.  That's why I didn't accept it as an answer.

Comment: Once again, you're returning a local temporary (see first comment). That's UB, end of story. No point in analyzing UB results. And variable-length arrays are a C extension, that's not standard C.

Comment: @Locke and i asked about the format of the csv file and a sample file because what you do in your function looks overly complicated for reading a csv.

Comment: I commented 5+ times to try to help you. Is that rude? I don't think so.

Comment: "because what you do in your function looks overly complicated for reading a csv" well, since you are ok with that ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never copying the last character of the line because you have `i < strlen(lineBuffer) - 1` in the `for` loop condition. Change that to `i < strlen(lineBuffer)`.

You also need to make a copy of the string before returning, you can't return a local array in C:

```
return strdup(tempString);
```

This also means that the caller needs to free this string when they're done with it, since `strdup()` allocates memory dynamically. Alternatively, you could use `malloc()` to allocate `tempArray()` in the first place, instead of declaring a local array.

Comment: That was it, the for loop condition.  Thank you so much.

Some further questions:  I thought strlen(lineBuffer) refers to the last space in the string, the null terminator?  Is that not the case?

Also: does `strdup` allocate memory dynamically behind the scenes?

Comment: Yes, `strlen()` returns the index of the null terminator. That's why you use `<` in the condition, to stop on the character before that, which is the last real character. If you were using `<=` then it would be correct to subtract 1.

Comment: Yes, `strdup()` allocates memory dynamically. That's why you need to free it.

Comment: Ahh, got it.  Thank you.  One last thing: it seems like the code is working fine without using `strdup`.  If it's undefined behavior, shouldn't it be breaking in this case?

Comment: @Locke The behaviour of undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @Locke Code that causes undefined behavior can sometimes seem to work. In this case, you might use the string before the memory that it was allocated in is reused for something else.